# Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudTable` but I'm receiving:

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException: 'Can not instantiate proxy of class: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudTable.
> Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
> System.Uri

```
var cloudTableMock = new Mock<CloudTable>
        (new Uri("http://unittests.localhost.com/FakeTable"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the signature for `CloudTable`, I see it takes an optional `TableClientConfiguration`:

```
public CloudTable(Uri tableAddress, TableClientConfiguration configuration = null);
```

Passing the default value of the optional parameter works:

```
var cloudTableMock = new Mock<CloudTable>
        (new Uri("http://unittests.localhost.com/FakeTable"));
        , It.IsAny<TableClientConfiguration>());
```

Comment: You can also use `It.IsAny<TableClientConfiguration>()` for the second parameter.